# Ambiguous use of 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I updated the Xcode to 14.3 and when I tried to run a project, I am getting this error:
"Ambiguous use of 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'"

Do you know how I can fix this issue ?

```
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        return dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTask
    }
}
```

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
associatedtype dataTaskProtocolType: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> dataTaskProtocolType

func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> dataTaskProtocolType }
```

This is my NetworkManager, where I got the following error:

"Value of type 'T.URLSessionDataTaskProtocol' has no member 'resume'"

```
class NetworkManager<T: URLSessionProtocol> {

let session: T

required init(session: T) {
    self.session = session
}

/// Errors that will be generated by the HTTPManager
enum HTTPError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case noInternet
    case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
}

///  Get data through an API call using a URL, returning a result type
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - url: A URL represting the location of the resource
///   - completionBlock: A completion closure returning the result type
public func get(url: URL, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    // make sure we pull new data each time
    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            completionBlock(.failure(error!))
            return
        }
        
        guard
            let _ = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                if let data = data {
                    completionBlock(.success(data))
                } else {
                    completionBlock(.failure(HTTPError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
                }
                return
            }
        // if passed guard
        if let data = data {
            completionBlock(.success(data))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is `URLSessionProtocol`?

Comment: Did this actually work before Xcode 14.3? Swift's name resolution rules must have changed...

Comment: It's hard to see what's the difference between the two methods: the one already existing in `URLSession` and the one you are calling, so I guess the compiler doesn't know which call in the `return`

Comment: @Sweeper yes it worked before Xcode 14.3

Comment: I updated my question with the URLSessionProtocol

Comment: Your are redefining dataTask in your extension. May be you made a mistake in the return type ?

Comment: I see. Then `URLSession` should conform to the protocol just by adding `typealias dataTaskProtocolType = URLSessionDataTask`. The sendabilities won't match though, so you might want to add some `@Sendable`s to the protocol methods.

Comment: @PtitXav but it was working before the Xcode update

Comment: @Sweeper can you write what you recommend as an answer to try it please ?

Comment: @LouizaA It's very similar to Daniel T's answer. That works for me. Your error message you got must be caused by some other part of your code, which you have not shown.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated my question with the NetworkManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
protocol URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
    func resume()
}

protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol
}

extension URLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTaskProtocol { }
extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol {
    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        self.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTask
    }

    func dataTask(with url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTaskProtocol {
        self.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completionHandler) as URLSessionDataTask
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: "Value of type 'T.URLSessionDataTaskProtocol' has no member 'resume'"

Comment: After your edit, I am getting the following error: "Ambiguous use of 'dataTask(with:completionHandler:)'" on the following line: "let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in "

Comment: I found the solution! The correct format is the following: " let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in "